# SQL Bulk Insert Operating system - Error code 123(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: sql-server

While trying to use Bulk Insert with SQL server, I am receiving the following error:

```
Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load because the file " C:\Users\Khandokar\Desktop\TEST_2016_beneficiaries.txt " could not be opened. Operating system error code 123(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.).
```

I have tried moving the file and using different paths with no success.  What might the issue be? Thanks!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[addBeneficiaries]
    @filePath NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
declare @sql varchar(max)
select  @sql='BULK INSERT dbo.beneficiaries FROM '' ';
select @sql = @sql + @filePath;
select @sql = @sql+ ' '' WITH(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
)';
exec(@sql)

EXEC dbo.addBeneficiaries 'C:\Users\Khandokar\Desktop\TEST_2016_beneficiaries.txt'
```

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question but, are the file in the same server as the one where you are running the bulk instruction?... also try to eliminate the extra spaces on your `FROM`

Comment: You are absolutely right - the extra spaces appears to be the issue. I am used to case sensitivity but not white-space sensitivity! Thank you so much!

Comment: I am glad to help KellyMarchewa :)